# any decent way to set a timeout on a thread?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, multithreading, embedded

We have a decoding function that runs in its own thread to carry out its job.
The time of execution is usually well below a defined timeout value, but on some occasions it may take much longer to complete. Thus the need to have a timeout in order to make sure this function will not cause extra delays to the rest of the program.

This is currently being developed on Windows OS but I'm also looking at a portable solution to Linux.

The implementation so far as multiple checks within the decoding function to see if it still has time to continue or abort processing. Which is def. not great practice and I'm looking at improving this.

I'm aware that boost provides such facility, but we do not use boost in this project.

Comment: I think that your current implementation is sensible if you are sharing data beteen threads and using mutexes. It will enable one to prevent deadlocks.

Comment: What's your question exactly? I've read your question a few times and can't figure out what you're asking.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, tittle edited :) I'd like to know if there's any good way to set a timeout on a thread, without having to code 'time checks' within the function itself (thread), which isn't pretty.

Comment: You're thinking about the problem backwards. Think about the work you want to do or not do. Don't think about the execution vehicles that happen to be doing the work. You don't want to timeout or stop a thread, you want to timeout or stop some particular job.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an excellent [article](http://www.drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=207100682&siteSectionName=parallele) by Herb Sutter on the subject. The conclusion would be: your current approach is OK. Just have your decoding threads periodicly check if they run out of time. The important thing is to strike a balance about how frequently you check.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to set a flag on timeout to instruct the thread instance to not report any completion, not continue and to delete/terminate itself ASAP.  Reduce its priority to the lowest possible and forget about it.  Create another thread object immediately, overwriting the old instance value, and use the new thread instance for subsequent decoding.

The lowest-priority orphaned thread will eventually die off itself when it finally gets around to checking its suicide-flag.